# What are the potentials of a battery with respect to earth?

Tags: electrostatics, potential

Assume an open-circuit voltaic cell. We know that the cell maintains a potential difference between its terminals. That is $V_+ - V_- = E$.

Now, if I connect $(-)$ to earth using the earth terminal in the mains, then $V_+ = E$ and  $V_- = 0$

And If I earth $(+)$, then $V_+ = 0$ and  $V_- = -E$

But what if I don't do any earthing at all? What then, is the potential of the terminals with respect to earth? (By earth I include every electrically irrelevant object, including myself)

Is $$V_+ = E/2, V_- = -E/2$$ If so, why?
I am stumped as to how I should determine the potential w.r.t any outside object. In fact, I wonder what the potential of the insulating body of the cell itself is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the battery is said to be "floating". Its potential with respect to earth can be suprisingly high or low. Small buildups of static electricity on the battery can easily charge it to hundreds or thousands of volts with respect to earth.

The voltage difference across the battery's terminals is still $1.5\,\text{V}$, but the voltage of the negative terminal may be $200\,\text{V}$, and the voltage of the positive terminal $201.5\,\text{V}$. You would not be able to measure this voltage with a multimeter, because the resistance of the multimeter (typically $1-10\,\text{M}\Omega$) would discharge this static electricity almost immediately.

Comment: Hmm. And is that also the potential of the body of the battery?

Comment: Yes, it would be. (Assuming there are no surfaces charges sitting on the body, or under the paint, [which sometimes happens.](http://www.esdjournal.com/static/shower/shower.html) Real-life electrostatics can get really complicated really fast.)